# Node.js - MongoDB - Asynch GET API How to Wait for Promise?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, azure-cosmosdb

I'm new to Node.js and MongoDB but am trying to figure out how best to implement a GET endpoint in Node.js/MongoDB/Express

For some reason, and I think it's because my database is an Azure Cosmos MongoDB, the only way that I can make a connection is to use `async` since what I understand as a synchronous db connection attempt skips over any other code and the connection is never made.

So here is my code so far:

```
    const app = express();

    app.get('/jobs', async (req, res) => { 
    var url = "mongodb://****************"
    const  client = new  MongoClient(url);
    await client.connect();
    console.log("connected to database");<--This works!
    const database = client.db("jobinfoaccount");<-This is the name of my Azure DB Resource
    const query = {"jobrequests":"123"}
    //jobrequests is the name of the collection in jobinfoaccount 
    var collection = database.collection("jobrequests").find().toArray(function (err,results) {
      console.log(results);
      res.json("Loaded" + results)
    })
  });
```

The problem that I am currently having us that the execution is blowing right by this line:

```
    var collection = database.collection("jobrequests").find().toArray (function (err,results)
```

And the execution doesn't even hit these lines:

```
      console.log(results);
      res.json("Loaded" + results)
```

When I look at the watch statement in VSCode, it says there's a promise there, but I am not sure how to handle this:

[image]

And when I call the endpoint in Postman, it just spins:

[image]

**UPDATE**
When I try using await as shown here:

```
var collection =  await database.collection("jobrequests").find().toArray (function (err,results) {
```

I still don't see it hitting the next line 70 going straight to line 73:
[image]

But collection seems to have resolved the promise:

[image]

Now I am wondering if there something wrong with one of these lines of code, in particular `jobinfoaccount` and `jobrequests`

```
const database = client.db("jobinfoaccount");
var collection =  await database.collection("jobrequests").find().toArray (function (err,results) {
```

This is my Resource Name in Azure:
[image]

And this is the Collection Name:

[image]

Thanks in advance..

Comment: If you use `var collection = await database.collection( ...`, does it work then?

Comment: Just tried that and updated my question for you.  Thanks

Comment: Hopefully someone familiar with CosmosDB can help.  I'm not sure what the Data Explorer is showing.

Comment: Did you tried to execute something like this: `await database.collection("jobrequests").find()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Trying to figure out how best to implement a GET endpoint in Node.js/MongoDB/Express.

**Below are the steps I tried to implement a GET endpoint in Node.js/MongoDB/Express:**

- The code I attempted creates a single MongoDB connection on server startup and then reuses it for each request. It avoids repeatedly creating and closing connections for every request.
- Consistent use of **async/await** makes the code more understandable and handles asynchronous tasks in a better manner.
- It is easier to debug and comprehend the data being retrieved by using the `console.log(results)` statement to record the retrieved data to the console before delivering it as a response.
- I attempted some code that uses `try/catch` to catch and handle any errors that arise when working with the database.
- The code below transmits the received data as a JSON response `(res.json(results))`, making it simple for client side to manipulate the data.
- For better code structure and readability, the route definition and MongoDB connection setup are separated in the code below.

**Code I tried with:**

```js
const express = require('express');
const { MongoClient } = require('mongodb');

const app = express();
const port = 3000; 
const url = '****'; 

app.use(express.json());
const client = new MongoClient(url);

async function connectToDatabase() {
  try {
    await client.connect();
    console.log('Connected to MongoDB');
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error connecting to MongoDB:', error);
  }
}
connectToDatabase();

// Retrieve all data from the database
app.get('/jobs', async (req, res) => {
  try {
        const database = client.db('newDb');
        const collection = database.collection('newColl'); 

        const results = await collection.find().toArray();
        console.log(results); 
        res.json(results);
  } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error:', error);
        res.status(500).json({ error: 'An error occurred' });
  }
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`);
});
```

**Output:**
In Console:

```
Server is running on port 3000
Connected to MongoDB
[
  {
    _id: new ObjectId("64f57a8e93de8d013cb645af"),
    id: '1',
    title: 'Job 1',
    description: 'This is the first job',
    location: 'New York'
  },
  {
    _id: new ObjectId("64f57ab993de8d013cb645b0"),
    id: '2',
    title: 'Job 2',
    description: 'This is the second job',
    location: 'Los Angeles'
  }
]
```

In Server: **localhost:3000/jobs**

```
[
    {
        "_id": "64f57a8e93de8d013cb645af",
        "id": "1",
        "title": "Job 1",
        "description": "This is the first job",
        "location": "New York"
    },
    {
        "_id": "64f57ab993de8d013cb645b0",
        "id": "2",
        "title": "Job 2",
        "description": "This is the second job",
        "location": "Los Angeles"
    }
]
```